# Is the coefficient for the least square quadratic risk function important?

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent, mean-square-error

I am working on my bachelor thesis about gradient descent. I have a problem understanding something in [this note](https://mathematical-tours.github.io/book-sources/optim-ml/OptimML.pdf).

In section 1.2 (linear regression) the author claims that

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\langle x , a_i \rangle - y_i)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \| Ax-y \|^2$$

is the least square quadratic risk function. As far as I know the risk function gives the average measure of loss, or expected loss. A loss function is a measure of how good a prediction model does in terms of being able to predict the expected outcome.

So I would have expeted a factor $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$. I would be grateful if someone could help me understand.

Comment: You could put any number since you will derivate. The $\frac12$ is convenient because $\frac12\times\color{red}{2}=1$,  the $\color{red}{2}$ coming from the derivative

Comment: From what i read so far, I assumed it was just a convenient choice. But doesn't this contradict my definition of a risk function?